# Splitting HDF5 file

Tags: data, dataset, hdf5-format

Below I am attaching the h5 file that I want to analyze.
There are two branches "S_F_VAL_0", "S_F_VAL_1"
Each branch has 10 branches, which then have a dataset that is a 3D array with dimensions 32*32*32.
[image]

This file is too large to analyze directly, so I am trying to divide the file into two files. For example, 1st file is composed of "S_F_VAL_0" -> "0.,2.,4.,6." and datasets below each branch. I tried to follow https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html, but it seems there is not enough information for me to do what I want. When I try to divide the group and save, it does not save the dataset and vice versa[image].

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?
Any help with writing a code or references might be very helpful!

Comment: How big is the file and how big are individual datasets? As long as a single dataset fits into your RAM you should be able to analyze it directly by importing datasets one by one.